# jQuery Mobile Slider Infinite Loop

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider, infinite-loop

I have a jquery mobile slider updated by network.

```
<input type="range" id="slider" class="slider osc" value="0" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" />
```

I receive new values by a socket, and I want to update my slider. When I receive data, the slider doesn't stop looping between its value and the one it receives. Any ideas?

```
socket.on('osc', function (data) {
    console.log('osc' , data);
    $("#slider").val(data.msg).slider('refresh') ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of refreshing the slider, would it work to call the `.page()` method on the jqm page itself?

This solution was offered in a similar post on the forum - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-dynamically-change-the-value-of-a-slider